# Can't move with find and exec?

Tags: php, linux, shell, find, exec

I have a simple problem, I can't resolve it. I have multiple files in: `/root/php` with the extension `*.php`

How can I move all the files with find and exec to the destination folder :

```
find /root/php -name "*.php" -exec mv /root/php/{} /root/destination/ \;
```

Error:

> mv: cannot stat '/root/php//root/php/asjdoiasdj.php': No such file or directory

Comment: Do you have `/root/php/asjdoiasdj.php`? Check with `ls -l /root/php/asjdoiasdj.php`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question, but purely about the use of a standard Linux command; it belongs over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux (where it will be most likely flagged as a duplicate)...

Comment: Protip: computers don't misspeak or misspell things in error messages. If `mv` says it can't find `/root/php//root/php/asjdoiasdj.php` then that's the filename it tried and failed to find. You should not think "oh, it probably meant it couldn't find `/root/php/asjdoiasdj.php`, so I'll look for that file instead "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /root/php -name "*.php" -exec mv {} /root/destination/ \;
```

You work on absolute paths in this case

Comment: To bulk move, you could use `-exec mv -t /root/destination {} +` (requires GNU `mv`), which calls `mv` as few times as possible instead of once per file to move.